# Displaying the spring boot exceptions in angular application

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I am developing the application with spring boot and angular, how I am going to display the exception in angular application

Comment: You should use some DTO and `ControllerAdvice` to map exceptions to json messages sent to front-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this all the time and it is luckily very easy.

The easiest/best way to do this globally for your whole application is to define and ExceptionHandler class. This class is a spring bean annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` and will catch exceptions globally and transform them into a standard format.

Something like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class JsonExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllOtherErrors(Exception exception) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(new ErrorResponse(exception.getMessage()));
    }

}
```

The error response class will just be something like this:

```
public class ErrorResponse {

    private String message;

    public ErrorResponse(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

P.S. You can handle different exceptions in a different way like this, in some cases you might want to throw a 400 bad request for a specific exception. All you need to do is add another method and change the exception in the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation.

...

Then from the angular side, you would have to check the HTTP response code and if the response code is not a success (e.g. 400, 500) you can read the response to see the error message.

The response would look something like this.

```
{
  "message": "Your exception message"
}
```

Which can just be read in angular through response.message (assuming javascript)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer similar method as Rawb mentioned above:

First, the controller:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

  @ExceptionHandler(UsernameNotFoundException.class)   
  public ResponseEntity<?> handleUsernameNotFoundExceptions(UsernameNotFound ex){
    Map<String, String> errors = new HasMap<>();
    errors.put("message", ex.getMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
   }
  }
```

Then make an error response class (no annotation needed):

```
 public class UsernameNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
   public UsernameNotFoundException(String username) {
    super("Can't find user with this username: " + username);
   }
 }
```

In angular you get the right status code (in this case 409 which is for Conflict) and the message which you easily can handle:

```
 { "message": "Can't find user with this username: username" }
```

There is a great explanation at Baeldung: [Error Handling for Rest with Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)

And the angular error Handling:
[Error Handling with Angular 8](https://rollbar.com/blog/error-handling-with-angular-8-tips-and-best-practices/)